# AWS - Find event source mapping UUID

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I need to import an event source mapping using Terraform and the [documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/lambda_event_source_mapping.html) says:

> terraform import aws_lambda_event_source_mapping.event_source_mapping
>   12345kxodurf3443

I cannot find the UUID of my resource anywhere, where is it?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the AWS CLI you can get the UUID parameter:

```sh
$ aws lambda list-event-source-mappings
{
    "EventSourceMappings": [
        {
            "UUID": "587ad24b-03b9-4413-8202-bbd56b36e5b7",
            "BatchSize": 1,
            "EventSourceArn": "arn:aws:kinesis:us-east-1:123456789012:stream/Logging",
            "FunctionArn": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:123456789012:function:LoggingStream",
            "LastModified": 1572309480.0,
            "LastProcessingResult": "OK",
            "State": "Enabled",
            "StateTransitionReason": "User action"
        }
    ]
}
```

You can also use the normal AWS API: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_ListEventSourceMappings.html

Ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/list-event-source-mappings.html

Answer (score 0):

Non CLI answer - Go to the SQS and choose the queue of your choice. Then look under Trigger tab, there is a column with uuid value for each of the trigger